# mandar listas por sockets del servidor al cliente

Tags: python, socket

una pregunta rapida he echo el tipico chat con sockets en python3 
 , el chat funciona bien pero tengo una duda en el servidor tengo el nombre de los usuarios guardados en una lista y me gustaria mandarsela a los clientes para que al lado del chat poner un recuadro con el nombre de los usuarios conectados ¿que tendria que usar para ello?

gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que el socket transporta bytes, tienes que convertir la lista a una secuencia de bytes. Típicamente hay dos formas para ello:

1. Usar un formato binario conocido por python. Para esto suele usarse el módulo `pickle` que es capaz de convertir cualquier tipo de datos pyhon a una serie de bytes, normalmente con el fin de guardarlo en disco, pero también, por qué no, para transmitirlo por un socket. Esto permitiría a quien lo recibe "recuperar" la variable enviada por si la quiere procesar localmente de alguna forma.
2. Usar un formato de texto, es decir una representación ASCII de tu lista. Esto puede ser más adecuado si simplemente quieres mostrarla en el otro lado, pues te bastaría un `print()`.

En tu caso, ya que asumo que tratándose de un chat el protocolo se basa en mensajes de tipo texto, la segunda opción sería la más apropiada.

Para convertir una lista (y otros tipos de datos habituales como diccionarios, etc.) a una cadena de texto tienes dos opciones:

1. Simplemente `str(lista)`. Esto te dará una cadena de caracteres con la representación de la lista. En la misma representación que verías si haces `print(lista)`, sólo que en este caso, en vez de imprimirla, la conviertes a bytes con `.encode()` y la envías por el socket. Quien la reciba la vuelve a convertir a caracteres Unicode con `.decode()` ya puede imprimirla. No obstante, si además de (o en vez de) imprimirla quiere procesarla de alguna forma, tendría que convertirla de nuevo a una lista python, y para esto puede ser más adecuado la siguiente opción.
2. Usar `import json` y `json.dumps(lista)`. Esto genera una cadena también, como el caso anterior, pero el contenido de la cadena sigue un formato llamado JSON. Si lo imprimes verás que es muy similar a cómo Python imprime una lista, sólo que usa comillas dobles en vez de simples, y cambian algunos detalles. La transmisión por el socket sería igual que el caso anterior (es decir, un `.encode()` para pasarlo a bytes y el correspondiente `socket.send()`). Al recibirlo reconstruyes la cadena con `.decode()` de los bytes recibidos. Y ahora la diferencia con el caso anterior es que es muy sencillo **reconstruir la lista python**, pues basta usar `json.loads(mensaje_recibido)`. Una vez tienes la lista ya podrías iterar por ella.

El formato JSON tiene además la ventaja de ser un estándar que puede ser consumido por clientes en otros lenguajes (típicamente JavaScript).

Comment: muchas gracias por contestar , lo cierto es que se me olvido mencionarlo pero estaba justo probando el modulo pickle pero me surgio un problema y es que el cliente esta continuamente recibiendo información del servidor porque lo tengo configurado para que el servidor reciba los mensajes de un cliente y lo reenvie a los demas entonces si mando la lista a los clientes la detectan como si fuese un mensaje y lo imprimen en el chat

Comment: Ya, pero si quieres "extender" el servidor para que pueda enviar listas (y quizás más adelante otras cosas que se te ocurran) además de mensajes, necesitarás alguna forma de distinguir ambas. Es decir, necesitarás "inventar" un protocolo. Quizás lo más sencillo en este punto pueda ser usar JSON y enviar un diccionario, que podría tener dos campos "tipo" y "contenido". De momento "tipo" podría ser "mensaje" o "usuarios", y en "contenido" tendrías el texto del mensaje, o la lista de usuarios. El cliente al recibir algo del servidor examinaría "tipo" para saber qué hacer con ello.

Comment: entiendo , eso hare muchas gracias

Comment: Dónde colocas el JSON `socket.send(datos_en_json)`? usando [este ejemplo de RealPython](https://realpython.com/python-sockets/#viewing-socket-state) lo logré con *sockets* bloqueantes (enviar cualquier JSON)... pero no entiendo cómo enviar esos JSON con el `multiconn-server.py` (todavía). Lo de ese ejemplo me funciona, pero: yo intento enviar cualquier dato que yo quiera en la respuesta, en lugar de simplemente devolver el mensaje del cliente como hace el ejemplo. `json.dumps(diccionario)` hizo el apaño con el "socket bloqueante", pero en el ejemplo "multi" no sé dónde poner ese mismo JSON...

Comment: Es decir: si hago `socket.send(json_en_bytes)`, me da error -> `[Errno 9] Bad file descriptor`. He hecho [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/596738/3436) que talvez ayude a la pregunta actual.