# ¿Cómo envío cualquier JSON desde el "server_socket" como respuesta a los mensajes recibidos desde el "client_socket"? (no-bloqueante)

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, socket, tcpip

Usando [este ejemplo de código de RealPython](https://realpython.com/python-sockets/#multi-connection-client-and-server) he podido hacer que dos máquinas se intercambien mensajes más o menos. Con la librería de Python3 llamada `socket`, puedo crear sockets con una dirección IP de servidor. El script del server recibe con éxito el mensaje del cliente y se lo devuelve del server al cliente con éxito. Ambos ejemplos me funcionan (tanto el de "sockets bloqueantes" como el de "sockets no-bloqueantes" del ejemplo de peticiones múltiples.

Incluso he conseguido, en el "ejemplo de sockets bloqueantes", que el script `server.py` permanezca a la escucha hasta que recibne el mensaje de la máquina cliente (`client.py`), procesa el mensaje recibido, envía otro dato diferente como respuesta hacia el cliente y justo después el `server.py` termina su ejecución con éxito junto con `client.py` en la otra máquina. Para pasar los datos de servidor a cliente uso diccionarios y los convierto a json usando `json.dumps(diccionario)`.

Lo malo es que quiero hacer eso mismo con los ejemplos de `multiconn-server.py` y `multiconn-client.py`, que usan **sockets no-bloqueantes** cuyo server socket permanece a la escucha indefinidamente atendiendo múltiples peticiones. Pero en el artículo no termina de quedar claro (a pesar de que sus códigos me funcionan siguiendo el ejemplo):

- ¿Cómo recibe exactamente el "socket de escucha" de `multiconn-server.py` cada uno de los dos mensajes del "socket cliente" de `multiconn-client.py`? En qué parte del bucle se confirma exactamente que la totalidad del mensaje fué recibida?
- ¿Cómo modifico el ejemplo para que, en lugar de limitarse a "rebotar de vuelta" los mensajes al remitente, `multiconn-server.py` envíe en la respuesta cualquier dato que yo quiera serializar en JSON?

Me imagino que los bucles van reconstruyendo el mensaje con fragmentos de bytes paquete por paquete con TCP o algo así. Pero no termino de comprender exactamente dónde sucede cada cosa en los "ejemplos multi", y no entiendo dónde meter exactamente las modificaciones que necesito.

## Lo que he logrado entender

- La propiedad `data` es un SimpleNamespace. Éste contiene los
  atributos `inb` y `outb` que parecen muy autoexplicativos. `inb` debe
  de ser el búfer binario de entrada, y `outb` el búfer binario de
  salida.
- De alguna forma, el código original de `multiconn_server.py` usa `recv_data` para obtener un mensaje del script `multiconn_client.py`en la máquina cliente. Luego, coge ese mismo mensaje del cliente y lo empaqueta en `outb` para que el servidor lo reenvíe de vuelta al cliente. **Sólo necesito entender cómo manipular estos procesos** para que, en vez de devolver el mensaje al remitente como si esto fuera un juego de ping-pong, empaquete una variable cualquiera (un string en JSON, por ejemplo). Pero aunque suene simple, hay muchas cosas no-obvias ocurriendo aquí, relacionadas con reconstruir a partir de paquetes TCP recibidos (o incluso la forma de empaquetar los enviados)... **estoy muy confuso**...

## Ya estoy muy cerca... oO

Parece que era tan sencillo como "reemplazar una línea de código del ejemplo por otra" (en concreto, un condicional de la función `service_connection` de `lib_server.py`)... aunque no del todo (no funciona exactamente como esperaba):

```
if recv_data:
    # XXX Antes...
    #data.outb += recv_data
    # XXX Ahora
    data.outb = json_response
else:
    print(f"Closing connection to {data.addr}")
    sel.unregister(sock)
    sock.close()
```

Esto hace lo que quería, sí: pero el ejemplo no hace lo que yo esperaba. Al parecer, el ejemplo recibe ambos mensajes, y los empaqueta "los dos juntos" en `outb` y los devuelve en una única respuesta (yo pensaba que ambos mensajes serían tratados como requests independientes, pero no). En otras palabras: para dos mensajes recibidos, envía el dato deseado **una única vez.**

Esto podría requerir "implementar algún protocolo distinto". Como, por ejemplo: algo que determine dónde termina un mensaje y empieza el otro (es decir, que yo haya visto no hay lógica alguna en ese código que intente diferenciar esto)

### Código del servidor

`multiconn-server.py` (aislando la lógica en librerías ad-hoc):

```
from lib_server import multi_listen_socket

multi_listen_socket()
```

---

`lib_tcp_generic.py` (contiene una función usada tanto por el cliente comp por el servidor)

```
import types, selectors

def accept_wrapper(sock, sel):
    conn, addr = sock.accept()  # Should be ready to read
    print(f"Accepted connection from {addr}")
    conn.setblocking(False)
    data = types.SimpleNamespace(addr=addr, inb=b"", outb=b"")
    events = selectors.EVENT_READ | selectors.EVENT_WRITE
    sel.register(conn, events, data=data)
```

---

`lib_server.py` (intento aislarlo en funciones reutilizables):

```
import socket, json
import sys, selectors, types
from lib_tcp_generic import accept_wrapper

# Este método envuelve lo de `multiconn-server.py`
def multi_listen_socket():
    sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()

    # Inicializar socket
    # host, port = sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2])
    # XXX Loopback -> puedes reemplazar por IP del servidor
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 65432
    lsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    lsock.bind((host, port))
    lsock.listen()
    print(f"Escuchando en {(host, port)}")
    lsock.setblocking(False)
    sel.register(lsock, selectors.EVENT_READ, data=None)

    # Loop de eventos
    try:
        while True:
            events = sel.select(timeout=None)
            for key, mask in events:
                if key.data is None:
                    accept_wrapper(key.fileobj, sel)
                else:
                    service_connection(key, mask, sel)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Interrupción de teclado, cerrando programa...")
    finally:
        sel.close()

def service_connection(key, mask, sel):
    sock = key.fileobj
    data = key.data
    response_dict = { "mensaje": "recibido",
                      "uno": 1,
                      "dos": "two",
                      "tres": [1,'dos',3] }
    response_jsonstr = json.dumps(response_dict)
    json_response = bytes(response_jsonstr, encoding="utf-8")

    if mask & selectors.EVENT_READ:
        try:
            # Debería estar listo para leer
            recv_data = sock.recv(1024)
        except ConnectionResetError:
            recv_data = None
            # [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
            print("ConnectionResetError --> Reiniciada por 'peer' -__-")
        if recv_data:
            data.outb += recv_data
            # TODO Qué es data.outb? Cómo lo reemplazo por cualquier JSON?
        else:
            print(f"Cerrando conexión con {data.addr}")
            sel.unregister(sock)
            sock.close()
        #sock.close()
    # XXX Si el servidor está listo para escribir en el socket
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_WRITE:
        if data.outb:
            # XXX Esto funcionaría en el ejemplo, PERO...
            '''
            print(f"Echoing {data.outb!r} to {data.addr}")
            sent = sock.send(data.outb)  # Should be ready to write
            data.outb = data.outb[sent:]
            '''

            # TODO XXX ...¿cómo lo adapto para enviar cualquier respuesta?
            # este intento daría crash con
            # OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
            sent = sock.send(json_response)
            data.outb = data.outb[sent:]
```

### Código del cliente

`multiconn-client.py` (a partir del ejemplo, aislado en funciones)

```
from lib_client import multi_connection_client_socket

multi_connection_client_socket()
```

`lib_client.py` (igual, aislando en funciones reutilizables):

```
import socket, json
import sys, selectors, types
from lib_tcp_generic import accept_wrapper

def multi_connection_client_socket():
    # INIT
    sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()
    messages = [b"Mensaje 1 del cliente.",
                b"Mensaje 2 del cliente."]

    # XXX Loopback: puede reemplazarse por IP del servidor
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 65432
    num_conns = 1
    # XXX Esto es un HACK que yo hice. Debería optimizarlo
    counter = num_conns * len(messages)
    start_client_connections(host, port, num_conns, messages, sel)

    # Bucle de eventos
    try:
        while counter > 0:
            events = sel.select(timeout=None)
            for key, mask in events:
                if key.data is None:
                    accept_wrapper(key.fileobj, sel)
                else:
                    service_connection_client(key, mask, messages, sel)
            counter -= 1
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Interrupción de teclado... cerrando cliente...")
    finally:
        sel.close()


def start_client_connections(host, port, num_conns, messages, sel):
    server_addr = (host, port)
    for i in range(0, num_conns):
        connid = i + 1
        print(f"Starting connection {connid} to {server_addr}")
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.setblocking(False)
        sock.connect_ex(server_addr)
        events = selectors.EVENT_READ | selectors.EVENT_WRITE
        data = types.SimpleNamespace(
            connid=connid,
            msg_total=sum(len(m) for m in messages),
            recv_total=0,
            messages=messages.copy(),
            outb=b"",
        )
        sel.register(sock, events, data=data)

def service_connection_client(key, mask, messages, sel):
    sock = key.fileobj
    data = key.data
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_READ:
        # Debería estar listo para leer
        recv_data = sock.recv(1024)
        if recv_data:
            print(f"Recibido {recv_data!r} desde la conexión de {data.connid}")
            data.recv_total += len(recv_data)
        if not recv_data or data.recv_total == data.msg_total:
            try:
                print(f"Cerrando conexión con {data.addr}")
            except AttributeError:
                print("Cerrando conexión... ¬¬")
            sel.unregister(sock)
            sock.close()
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_WRITE:
        if not data.outb and data.messages:
            data.outb = data.messages.pop(0)
        if data.outb:
            print(f"Enviando {data.outb!r} a la conexión {data.connid}")
            # Debería estar listo para escribir
            sent = sock.send(data.outb)
            data.outb = data.outb[sent:]
```

Comment: te he votado de forma negativa por varios motivos: 1) no debes usar link a codigos externo, incluye todo lo necesario en tu pregunta. 2) tienes multiples dudas y preguntas que resolver, esperariamos que fuese una pregunta por post y concentrarnos en solo una duda.

Comment: 3) tu duda no esta relacionada al codigo en si o su implementacion, esta mas relacionada a backend y logica de la libreria y a la manipulacion, este tipo de dudas seria recomendadas exponerlas al sitio del proveedor de la libreria. quien deberia de darte una mejor explicacion o actualizar su documentacion, cualquier respuesta que te den aqui puede estar basadas en opiniones.

Comment: estoy tambien solicitando el cierre de la pregunta por estar basada en opiniones y enfoque, por tanto incluso ser muy compleja.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 No os preocupéis: ya os ahorro las molestias. Ya la borro yo mismo - oops no puedo. Está bloqueada. Otros usuarios han puesto también su esfuerzo... así que hala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posible solución rápida (seguramente no la más óptima, pero funciona):

Tan simple como cambiar una única línea de código de los ejemplos "no-bloqueantes" en la función `service_connection` para el socket del servidor:

```
if recv_data:
    # XXX Antes...
    #data.outb += recv_data
    # XXX Ahora
    data.outb = json_response
else:
    print(f"Cerrando conexión con {data.addr}")
    sel.unregister(sock)
    sock.close()
```

Claro que, el resultado no era el que esperaba yo (aún así aceptable de momento)... resulta que, al parecer, el protocolo de respuesta del socket del servidor no trata ambos mensajes enviados por el cliente como consultas independientes; ya que **junta ambos mensajes en un único paquete de respuesta en el ejemplo**. Ergo, con mi modificación: ambos mensajes son respondidos con mis datos deseados **una única vez** ( talvez aún así el protocolo sea aceptable por ahora ).

A partir de aquí, podré ir refactorizando y optimizando. Ya tengo un punto de partida.

Más tarde, me he dado cuenta de algo destacable. El SimpleNameSpace utilizado en el ejemplo en el cual se basa el código de la pregunta tiene los búfers binarios de E/S `data.inb` y `data.outb`. El ejemplo original escribe los datos recibidos directamente en `outb`, y eso es un *hack* (te ahorra una línea de código en el ejemplo, sí; pero lo normal es usar `inb` para los datos entrantes y `outb` para los salientes.

Comment: te he dado un voto negativo por que una *Posible solucion* no es una *solucion*.

Comment: cuando escribirmos una respuesta esperamos que las respuesta sean de calidad y realmente solucionen cualquier duda que tenga la persona y sobre todo que sea reutilizable para cualquier otro programador (comunidad) de busque o tenga el mismo problema.

Comment: Para mí lo fué. Acepto el voto negativo porque seguramente no es lo más óptimo, y necesita refactorización. Aunque a mí me valga...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 un posible solución puede dar inicio o inspiración a otra solución :)

Comment: EL motivo principales por el cual no he desarrollado más la respuesta es: lo que necesitaba entender es cómo manipular el input/output a voluntad a partir del código del ejemplo. Finalmente lo entendí (de ahí la respuesta). Y a partir de aquí tengo que escalarlo: *y aún me quedan muchas decisiones de arquitectura que tomar al respecto* .

Comment: Aún me quedan cosas por comprender: 1- ¿Salta primero el evento READ y luego el WRITE, como parece ser? 1- ¿Cómo puedo estar seguro de que READ terminó su trabajo, para luego "cocinar" un dato y, cuando este dato esté listo, pasarlo al evento WRITE? etc. etc. etc. Cosas que, de momento, investigaré por mi cuenta.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes razón en que es necesario ampliar el protocolo para demarcar dónde acaba un mensaje y comienza el siguiente. El programa original no lo necesitaba porque le bastaba hacer eco de todo lo que recibiera, ya fuera parte del mismo mensaje o no.

Una forma típica de demarcar mensajes es introduciendo un caracter especial que actúe como terminador. Debes elegir uno que nunca aparecería dentro del mensaje en sí. En protocolos orientados a líneas podría ser el `\n`. Tienes que modificar tanto cliente como servidor para que incluyan ese terminador en cada mensaje que emitan. También tienen que procesarlo adecuadamente durante las recepciones.

Por ejemplo, tras recibir un trozo y concatenarlo al campo `inb`, buscarías si dentro de `inb` aparece el terminador. Si aparece, te quedas con todo lo que había antes de él, y ese sería un mensaje completo, en base al cual crearías la respuesta que iría a `outb`. Y actualizas `inb` para que se quede solo con lo que había tras el terminador. Si no aparece, no haces nada. Es decir, sólo escribes una respuesta en `outb` cuando te haya llegado un mensaje completo (que es cuando el terminador aparezca entre los bytes recibidos).

Fijate que pudiera ser también que al recibir un nuevo "trozo", éste contenga dos terminadores, porque han llegado varios mensajes. Eso puede complicar las cosas.

Por otro lado, entiendo que como ejercicio de programación de "bajo nivel" quieras aprender a usar este modelo de programación, pero ya estás viendo que da lugar a un código muy difícil de comprender y mantener. Para escribir código asíncrono con sockets no bloqueantes la forma moderna es usar `asyncio`.

Para que compares, este sería el servidor que hace lo que he descrito, usando asyncio:

```py
import asyncio
import json

TERMINADOR = b'\n'

async def gestionar_cliente(reader, writer):
    try:
        while True: # Bucle infinito para atender al cliente
            data = await reader.readuntil(TERMINADOR)  # Recibir solo hasta terminador
            mensaje = data.decode("utf-8").rstrip()    # Preparar respuesta
            respuesta = json.dumps({"mensaje": mensaje}) + "\n"
            writer.write(respuesta.encode())           # encolarla para enviar
            await writer.drain()                       # esperar hasta que haya sido enviada
    except asyncio.IncompleteReadError: # Esto ocurre si el cliente cierra
        print("El cliente ha cerrado")
    finally:
        writer.close()

async def main():
    servidor = await asyncio.start_server(gestionar_cliente, '127.0.0.1', 8888)

    async with servidor:
        # La siguiente linea es en realidad un bucle infinito
        # pero se puede salir con CTRL+C
        await servidor.serve_forever()

# Esta es la forma de poder lanzar funciones asíncronas
asyncio.run(main())
```

Observa que todo el código tiene apariencia de código síncrono, pues se lee secuencialmente. Pero cada vez que se hace `await`, el código no queda ahí bloqueado, sino que vuelve al bucle de control (que es invisible, pues lo gestiona asyncio), dando oportunidad a entrar a otros clientes u otras instancias de la función `gestionar_cliente()` (pues se creará una nueva cada vez que llegue un cliente).

Este código por tanto puede trabajar con varios clientes simultáneos, y sin necesidad de usar hilos o multiproceso. Puedes probar a conectar varios clientes al mismo y ver cómo los atiende a todos (por ejemplo, puedes usar `telnet` o `nc` como clientes genéricos)

```bash
$ telnet localhost 8888
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Hola
{"mensaje": "Hola"}
que tal
{"mensaje": "que tal"}
```

Comment: Cuando tenga tiempo,. le echaré un vistazo a esta solución... tiempo... algo que me va a escasear mucho a partir de hoy...

Comment: Así que usas una librería llamada `asyncio` en lugar de la libería `socket`... interesante...

Comment: asyncio no es (solo) un reemplazo de socket. Es una librería genérica para hacer programación concurrente mediante corutinas en lugar de hilos o procesos. Todo se ejecuta en un solo hilo, pero la ejecución avanza "saltando" de una tarea a otra por cachitos. Cada vez que una tarea hace `await` porque se va a bloquear, le está cediendo el turno a otra. asyncio incluye sus propios objetos para hacer entrada/salida no bloqueante, ya sea a sockets o a ficheros, que "colaboran" con este mecanismo asíncrono (a diferencia de las bibluiotecas de sockets o E/S estándar que son bloqueantes por defecto).

Comment: Entonces, `socket` es de "bajo nivel" (en el sentido estrictamente programático) y asyncio tiene mayor nivel de abstracción? Talvez acabe probando esta alternativa más tarde... por ahora sigo trasteando con el código resultante del ejemplo del artículo... y estoy acabando con muchas más preguntas que al principio ( y eso sería tema para otra pregunta; es decir; si tuviese ganas de volver a preguntar nada )